# Como posso "adiar" a inicialização de uma propriedade?

Tags: propriedade, kotlin

Existem situações em que a inicialização da propriedade não é possível de ser feita na declaração, o seu valor só é conhecido mais tarde.

Um exemplo disso é, no Android, as referências às *views* de um *layout* só poderem ser obtidas após ser usado o método `setContentView()`.

Existe algum modo de "adiar" a inicialização sem a necessidade de declarar a propriedade como *nullable*?

Comment: *Iniciativa Kotlin! seja mais um colaborador fazendo uma pergunta no SOPT*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provavelmente a forma mais simples seria:

```
public lateinit var prop: String

fun init(param: String) {
   valor = Executa(param)
}
```

Kotlin tem [propriedades](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) de forma muita parecida com as propriedades de C#, com uma sintaxe melhor, então pode parecer que ali tem um campo, mas é uma propriedade, mesmo que não tivesse o `lateinit`.

Coisas como `setContentView()` são uma impedância de Kotlin com Java porque usa o jeito simulado de propriedade do Java. Até teria como solucionar isso mesmo que não de forma simples. Eu acho que valeria o esforço em nome da padronização de estilo na linguagem, faria como TypeScript resolveu a impedância com JavaScript.

Tem várias outras formas. Veja sobre [`lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/lazy.html) e [propriedades delegadas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

```
val lazyValue: String by lazy {
    println("computed!")
    "Hello"
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/LazyProperty.kt).

Desta forma só quando ela for necessária é que será inicializada. Em geral usa-se isto para algo que pode nunca ser necessário para o objeto e para gerar seu valor pode ter um processamento pesado ou que pode ter uma valor alterado durante o processo entre a criação do objeto e seu primeiro uso.

Desta forma pode usar com `val` já que a inicialização ocorre tardiamente. Sem o `lateinit` um `val` precisa de um valor já que não pode mais ter seu valor alterado. Ele fica em um estado inválido até ser necessário, o que é diferente de ter um valor nulo e depois ter outro valor.