# Qual é o objetivo do internal lateinit?

Tags: java, kotlin

Converti para o *Kotlin* um simples `Fragment` com um botão qualquer. Na alternância, basicamente ficou assim:

**Java**

```
private Button btn;
```

**Kotlin**

```
internal lateinit var btn: Button
```

Qual é o objetivo do `internal lateinit`? Seria a substituição do `private`?

Comment: Aqui tem uma explicação: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: Quem negativou poderia explicar o motivo?! Se você enxergou algo que possa ser melhorado na pergunta, seria interessante deixar um comentário.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `internal` é um meio termo entre o `private` e o `public`. Ele é público se considerar que o membro pode ser acessado fora do seu objeto, mas é privado se considerar que só o que está no mesmo módulo pode acessar esse membro.

Então é como você dizer "olha, quem for classe irmã, ou seja, faz parte deste módulo pode acessar isso aqui, os demais não podem". É uma forma de liberar um detalhe de implementação de uma classe que seria muito difícil fazer sem isto, mas proteger para não virar bagunça e todo mundo poder acessar.

Sempre que você expõe algo publicamente tem que tomar cuidado com toda manutenção para não quebrar código que usam aquilo. O privado ajuda porque fica contido. O interno é quase isso porque é garantido que se alguém está usando, pelo menos é no mesmo módulo que você tem acesso, então é quase um privado, pelo menos se o projeto for bem organizado.

Um módulo é uma unidade de compilação, parece com um pacote do Java, mas não é bem ele.

O `private` ainda é útil para diminuir a visibilidade.

[Documentação de visibilidades](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html).

O `lateinit` não tem relação direta, acho que já foi respondido em [Como posso "adiar" a inicialização de uma propriedade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227407/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).